# Is it possible to create a Microsoft Practices Enterprise Library Data Access Block Database from a DbConnection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, enterprise-library

I have a DbConnection object (coming from an EntityFramework 4.0 context) and was wondering if it is possible to create a Microsoft Practices Enterprise Library Data Access Block Database (Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database). Does anyone know if it is possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Can you get the connection string instead, and use it to create an EL DAAB Database?